# Matching values in columns in R

Tags: r, multiple-columns

I have 2 large csv files that contain information about the same shops.

File1:

```
Dates1            Sales
02-11-2017        100
04-11-2017        90
01-08-2016        80
01-02-2013        99
01-09-2016        12
```

File2:

```
Dates2            Stores
02-11-2017        A
04-11-2017        B
01-09-2016        C
```

What I need is find the matching dates and create the following table:

```
NewDates          Stores  Sales
02-11-2017        A       100
04-11-2017        B       90
01-09-2016        C       12
```

The files have different number of rows and the same date can be contained in a different row in the respecting file. Can you please help me solve this in R?

Comment: Maybe you can use the `sqldf` package

Comment: This is a simple merge:  `merge(df1, df2, by.x = 'Dates1', by.y = 'Dates2')`

Comment: or using `inner_join(df1, df2, by = c("Dates1" = "Dates2"))` from the `dplyr` package

Comment: Another way: file2$sales <- file1[match(file2$dates2, file1$dates1), 2]

Answer (score 1):

```
library(data.table)

df1 <- fread("file1")
df2 <- fread("file2")

merge(df1, df2, by.x = 'Dates.1', by.y = 'Dates.2')
```

The `data.table` package can handled large files.